# Determining if a theory in first-order logic is decidable

Tags: model-theory, computability

We have a theory in first-order logic which we know that is uncountably categorical, complete but not finitely axiomatisable. We also want to know if it is decidable. But I don't know the procedure for finding this out. Can someone give me a starting point?

I have the theory given explicitly but I want to avoid sharing too much here since it is a homework assignment and I need to solve it by myself.

Edit: According to comments, we have that a theory is decidable if it is recursively axiomatized. Can someone show me why or direct me to the theorem?

Comment: If it is recursively axiomatized, then it is decidable. Informal proof: One can make an explicit list of all possible proofs. For any $\varphi$, one or the other of $\phi$ or $\lnot\varphi$ will show up at the end of a proof.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank for your response, the theory is clearly recursively axiomatized (if I understand that correctly, which I think I do). But how do we know that it follows that it is decidable? Is there a name for this theorem?

Comment: @Sid: Use the "informal proof" given by André. In the proof it is crucial that you know that your theory is complete. Indeed, for complete theories (but not in general) it is known that "decidable" coincides with "recursively axiomatizable".

Comment: @Sid: The general fact here is that a theory which is complete and recursively axiomatisable is always decidable, and I think this is too easy to show to warrant having a special name...

Comment: @Sid: The informal proof was in fact a description of an algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the theory is recursively axiomatizable by a set of axioms $T$, then the predicate "$n$ encodes a proof from $T$" is recursive.

Since $T$ is complete, for every $\varphi$ in the language either $T$ proves it or it proves its negation. From this you can prove that both the set of provable, and the set of non-provable are recursively enumerable, and therefore recursive.

Comment: Doesn't the language of the cardinality matter? or are they automatically considered to be countable?

Comment: If it is recursively axiomatizable, then it is necessarily countable.

Comment: But OP doesn't mention anything about the theory being recursively axiomatizable.

Comment: Perhaps you should read the last sentence [of the question] again.

Comment: Ah, ok. Sorry. I was thinking about the original question (the part before it says edit). So in this case you have to show that uncountably categorical will give you decidable (or get a counter example). I was thinking along the lines of taking a language with lots of constants and tweaking the theory of equality for a counter example.

Comment: Danul, deciability is inherently linked with the natural numbers. So nothing uncountable can be effectively decidable. I don't much on the topic, but it might be possible to argue something about uncountable theories if they can be written as a countable union of schemas (like if you have uncountably many constants and you consider the schema that two are distinct); but as I said, I don't know much about that.

Comment: OK. That was kind of my conclusion as well. Thank you! I was just trying to figure out where the uncountable categoricity came in to play and whether there were generalizations of decidability to languages of higher cardinality that I'm not aware of were floating around and impacting the discussion.

Comment: Categoricity comes into play as it implies completeness.

Comment: But OP already has completeness listed. And it is stronger than completeness.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks for this. Just to be in the clear though, how do you know that a given theory $T$ is recursively axiomatized? My textbook does not define this so I take it as $T$ having a recursive set of axioms?

Comment: @Sid: Much like being finitely axiomatizable means that there is a finite subset from which we can prove the rest of the theory; being recursively axiomatizable means that there is a recursive set of axioms.